# How do carriers work in a bipolar junction transistor?

Tags: bjt

Why do the carriers from the emitter to the base all recombine? Why do some of them make the base current though there is an electric field in the collector base junction?

Answer (score 2):

> Why do the carriers from the emitter to the base all recombine?

*Presuming that the emitter(s), base, and collector(s) all have metallic connections to the outside world*, it's because holes don't exist in metal, and because the equilibrium condition of any semiconductor is to have a certain concentration of minority carriers and a certain concentration of majority carriers.

With nowhere to escape *too*, and statistics working against them, excess holes pretty much have to recombine with excess electrons.

> Why do some of them make the base current though there is an electric field in the collector base junction?

Because the base is flooded with both majority and minority carriers.  Majority carriers are being supplied by the base connection and the collector, and minority carriers are being supplied by the emitter.

Even though the electric field is doing its best to sweep the minority carriers into the collector, they spend a finite amount of time in the base, in the company of a whole bunch of majority carriers.  It's inevitable that some of them will combine.

Comment: Should the last sentence say "majority carriers" for one of the two instances of "minority carriers"? (I might also be sleep deprived to the point of forgetting basic semiconductor physics, so apologies if my comment is just a fundamental error on my part)

Comment: Good catch; thanks.

Comment: The expression "the base is flooded with both majority and minority carriers" might give the wrong impression. "Flooded" is not a quantitative term, and can mean different things to different people. But if the emitter is, say, 100 times more heavily doped than the base, ( not an atypical figure), then most of the carriers in the base, when the transistor is "on", will be minority carriers. The ratio between minority carriers to majority carriers will be somewhere in the neighborhood of 100:1. Not the impression one might get from the words "flooded with majority carriers"...

Answer (score 2):

I'll address your second question with a little more detail. I'll use a PNP example because I feel what I write may be a little more readily absorbed.

In an ideal world all of the holes injected by the emitter into the base would move along to the collector to be 'collected.' One way of trying to do this is to make the base *very thin*. With less travel distance required to get through the base and into the collector, there's simply less chance of something going awry (like a recombination event.) Another way is to make the lifetimes of holes longer by making the diffusion length for holes in the base very much longer than the *neutral* N material width in the base. Yet another is to try and ensure that the emitter current is *all* holes moving from the emitter to the base and *not* electrons going from the base to the emitter. Doping the base lightly, compared to the emitter, helps achieves this.

For all the good done above, reality impinges. The two bigger remaining effects relating to the required base current are (1) that there must be at least some little bit of recombination taking place between all those injected holes from the emitter matching up with electrons in the base and that these electrons lost to recombination must be resupplied by the base contact point (if not, the base would gradually charge up sufficiently to refuse any further holes from the emitter and that would be very bad), and also (2) some electrons will, despite lightly doping the base with respect to the emitter, still unfortunately get injected from base to emitter and, of course, also need to be replaced/resupplied by the base contact point.

There's another very minor 'compensation' helping *reduce* the base current. But it's almost totally unimportant. Some electrons do get thermally generated in the collector and some are agitated over into the base. And these few will just slightly reduce the necessary base current (required for the other two big reasons.)